# What is B2Bot? Can you define it?

Tags: bots, keyword

Can you reveal the definition of what a B2Bot is? I couldn't find anything.
The word is taken from [this](https://research.aimultiple.com/chatbot-benefits/) article. In 4th point.

PS:Maybe instead of giving minuses to the question, you can tell me what's wrong with it?

Comment: What's wrong with it? It's not a programming question.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular what kind of question is this ? bots are not related to programming ?

Answer (score 0):

I **think**, B2Bot is "Business to Bot", its when a business spends the effort to create a bot

Comment: i couldn't find anywhere this acronym or term as a software / code term, can you add a link ?